# How to convert key:value pair in json as key = value in mule

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I am trying to form where clause from the JSON file. I want to fetch the key:value pair from the where part of below input and convert it into key = value

Input:

```
{
   "Table":{
      "TableName":"Employee",
      "Columns":[
         "ID",
         "Name"
      ],
      "Where":{
         "ID":"A-0001",
         "Name":"xyz"
      }
   }
}
```

Expected Output:
I want to get `where ID = 'A-0001' and Name = 'xyz'`

I am using mule 4. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Building dynamic SQL? I would suggest avoiding that and sticking to parameterized queries.

I would strongly urge you to use this path: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/db/database-connector-examples#use-input-parameters-to-protect-database-queries

It would be really easy to make this parameterized because all you'd have to do is passing in `payload.Table.Where` as your parameterized object.

If you're pulling this from some kind of trusted source and have to do things this way I suppose you could ignore the columns array and do it this way pretty easily:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
if (payload.Table.Where?)
    "where " ++ ((payload.Table.Where pluck "$($$) = '$($)'") reduce ($$ ++ " and " ++ $))
else
    ""
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but if you wanted to still use the columns array you could also do this.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"where " ++ (
    payload.Table.Columns reduce ((col, wClause="") -> 
        if (not payload.Table.Where[col]?) wClause
        else wClause ++ (if (wClause != "") " and " else "") ++ ("$(col) = '$(payload.Table.Where[col])'")
    )
)
```

Comment: Agreed. The script is cool but it is an SQL injection vulnerability waiting to happen.

Comment: Thank you. I do agree that it would cause SQL injection and I am still new to Mule and learning. This is just a POC which is still under discussion phase. Thanks Michael the solution worked. And I will surely keep in mind about the drawbacks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another take at a similar approach.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"where " ++ ((payload.Table.Where mapObject {
     ($$): (($$) ++ "=" ++ "'" ++ ($) ++ "'") 
}) pluck ($) joinBy " and ")
```

Comment: `mapObject` is unnecessary here: `payload.Table.Where pluck "$($$) = '$($)'" joinBy " and "`

Comment: And the `joinBy` is just a `map` to first explicitly coerce everything into strings chained with a `reduce` which makes it the same solution with an extra `mapObject` and `map` thrown in :)