# How to loop thru or iterate an array list and then concatenate the values in Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have an input payload [id, name]. Based on this input, I want to loop through each value in the array and form a where clause for my select statement.

Input:

```
{
"column": ["id","name"]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
"id == '123' and name == 'abc'"
```

With one column I am able to do, but with multiple columns how to iterate and then concatenate?

Comment: Where are the values corresponding to these keys ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert key:value pair in json as key = value in mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758620/how-to-convert-keyvalue-pair-in-json-as-key-value-in-mule)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you lookup values from another array , you could do something crude like this.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var values = [2,"test"]
---
payload.column map 
{ 
    a: $ ++ " == " ++ "'" ++ values[($$)] ++ "'"
}.a  joinBy " and "
```